# Export Excel by Javascript/Jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, excel

**View:**

```
<button onclick="ExportExcell()" type="button">Export to Excell</button>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.Raw(ViewData["html"].ToString());
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
function ExportExcell() {

window.location.href = "Report/ExportLevyToExcell?="
+ @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["html"]));


 }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ExportLevyToExcell()
    {
        var result = ViewData["html"];
        //Process....
    }
```

I tried to post ViewData["html"] to ExportLevyToExcell in controller.However i am seeing syntax error for javascript code.How can i post Viewdata by using javascript jquery thanks.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does it related to Export Excel? It seems to be passing data from view to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are your trying to achieve here, I see several issue in your code.

> I tried to post ViewData["html"] to ExportLevyToExcell in controller.
>
> However I am seeing syntax error for javascript code. How can I post
> Viewdata by using javascript jquery.

You don't read values out of ViewData in controller. These structures are for controller to share some little data with view (ideally view should get data through model i.e. strongly typed view).

You can send data from view to controller in QueryString or FormBody. As an example, If you write controller like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportLevyToExcell(string data)
{
    var result = data;

    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

and change your JS code a bit like this:

```
function ExportExcell() {

    var data = '@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["html"]))';

    window.location.href = "Home/ExportLevyToExcell?data=" + data;
}
```

When you click on button, you will see controller receive the value of

> ViewData["html"]

I wish to be of more help however not sure what exactly you want to achieve.